# How to create a List with custom JSON data

Tags: react-admin

I have data coming from the Firestore db. I created multiple resources with test collections coming from Firestore and it worked very well. The problem I'm having now, is that I have a collection with one single document and one of this document's collection has a field with a huge json data, so the structure would be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "rj2PK96j3MashOA1AVFh",
        "timestamp": "2023-11-15T15:26:18.628Z",
        "snapshot": "{\"guests\": [{\"id\":\"41090\",\"id_transaction\":\"41755\",\"id_people\":\"33100\",\"status\":\"checkin\",\"paid_days_in_advance_to_partner\":\"2\",\"nights_to_pay\":\"13\",\"id_bed\":\"87\",\"id_key\":\"88\",\"room_type_id\":\"1\",\"original_checkout_plan\":\"2023-10-02\",\"checkout_plan\":\"2023-10-13\",\"checkout_confirmed\":{}}}",
        "updated": "2023-11-02T15:39:48.536Z",
        "domain": "testing"
    }
]
```

Using the regular structure of List/Datagrid/TextField components I can have access to all the values, including the stringfied json displayed in a RA list. But I want the "snapshot" field to render each json key without losing the  capabilities. I have tried many different approaches, this below is the most recent where I get the whole data, then I get the snapshot json string, parse into json then I try to map through each "guest" and try to render its data using TextField components, and it renders nothing on my screen. (See the image). But I have access to all data in the console.

```
const SnapshotList = () => {
  const { data, resource } = useListContext();
  const snapshotString = data[0].snapshot;

  try {
    const snapshotJson = JSON.parse(snapshotString);
    const todaysGuests = snapshotJson.assign_today.guests;

    // Log todaysGuests to the console
    console.log("Todays Guests:", todaysGuests);

    return (
      <Datagrid>
        {todaysGuests.map((guest: any, index: any) => (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <TextField
              label="Arrival Date"
              source={`${guest}.arrival_date`}
            />
            <TextField
              label="Reservation Code"
              source={`${guest}.reservation_code`}
            />
            <TextField
              label="Given Name"
              source={`${guest}.given_name`}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </Datagrid>
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
    return null; // or handle this case according to your requirements
  }
};
```

```
export const Snapshots = () => (
  <ResourceContextProvider value="snapshots">
    <List pagination={<Pagination perPage={1000} rowsPerPageOptions={[]} />}>
      <SnapshotList />
    </List>
  </ResourceContextProvider>
);
```

Does anyone have any idea on how can I generate the Datagrid using the TextField passing custom resources to it?

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation you pass keys to Datagrid to retrieve fields: source={`${guest}.arrival_date`},
but you don’t pass array of records itself - `data`.

You need to combine the original array of `data` records and your data from `todaysGuests` and pass new array in Datagrid.

An example of a Datagrid implementation with an external data source - ["Standalone Usage"](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html#standalone-usage).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could leverage [`<WithRecord>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/WithRecord.html).

Something like this:

```
const SnapshotList = () => (
  <Datagrid>
    <WithRecord
      label="Arrival Date"
      render={(record) => (
        <TextField record={JSON.parse(record.snapshot)} source="arrival_date" />
      )}
    />
    <WithRecord
      label="Reservation Code"
      render={(record) => (
        <TextField
          record={JSON.parse(record.snapshot)}
          source="reservation_code"
        />
      )}
    />
    <WithRecord
      label="Given Name"
      render={(record) => (
        <TextField record={JSON.parse(record.snapshot)} source="given_name" />
      )}
    />
  </Datagrid>
);
```

Another option is to use [`withLifecycleCallbacks`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/withLifecycleCallbacks.html) to change the record `afterRead` so that it contains an already parsed `snapshot` field, and then you can do simply:

```
const SnapshotList = () => (
  <Datagrid>
    <TextField label="Arrival Date" source="snapshot.arrival_date" />
    <TextField label="Reservation Code" source="snapshot.reservation_code" />
    <TextField label="Given Name" source="snapshot.given_name" />
  </Datagrid>
);
```